# Can an Erlang supervisor monitor and restart a C-node?

Tags: c, erlang, erlang-otp, erlang-supervisor

I'm running an external C service application. I'd like to add a C-node to the application so that I can interface with it from within Erlang. Just wonder if I can put the C-node in the supervisor child spec so that the supervisor can monitor and restart the service if necessary?

Comment: Have you read this post? http://erlang.2086793.n4.nabble.com/about-Erlang-C-Node-monitor-td2118516.html